# how to read delimited file with '/' and space in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io

I want to read this file in MATLAB, the file contains these data

```
1/1/2008 1110 98.5
1/2/2008 1110 99.5
1/3/2008 1110 96.5
1/4/2008 1110 32.5
1/5/2008 1110 8.56
1/6/2008 1110 48.5
```

it should be in five columns:

- 1st column is the month
- 2nd column is the day
- 3rd column is the year
- 4th column is the 1110
- 5th column is the last column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) function:

```
%# parse file (change the data types if necessary)
fid = fopen('file.dat','rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%d/%d/%d %d %f', 'Delimiter',' ');
fclose(fid);

%# put columns in separate variables
[dt_month,dt_day,dt_year,val1,val2] = deal(C{:});

%# convert to serial date
dt = datenum(double(dt_year),double(dt_month),double(dt_day));
```

Comment: thank you Mr. Amro

i found the answer that i want:

data = textscan(fid,'','delimiter','/\t')

and this was the output:

1  6  2008  1110  48

Comment: If you don't specify a formatting string, it will try to read floating-point numbers `%f`, also you can specify multiple delimiters as you did `['/' '\t']`